# The file link in yii2 html debug site is not working. How to make the link ide://open?url=file:///... work?

Tags: hyperlink, yii2, ide

Yii2 provides very nice debug tool. It shows all calls to database and also links to files where the database is being accessed. These link have a form of:

```
ide://open?url=file:///var/www/yii2-advanced/common/models/User.php&line=121
```

Firefox is unfortunately not able to open them by default. Do you how to open the link by single click? It would be much better to search the code in browser and once you know where is the problem, switch back to normal IDE.

I think that it needs to be configured in Firefox and is therefore more software not code related, but it is also very specific problem with Yii2 and the Yii2 community is mainly / only code related.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the right click menu on link and choose  open in a new tab

or press the CTRL when you click the link

or if you really want change the default Firefox setting  use the

```
about:config  (in the url bar )
```

and search  for

```
browser.link.open_newwindow
```

double click to change the value to 1

Answer (score 0):

You can configure how these links looks like using `traceLine` property:

```
'modules' => [
    'debug' => [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'traceLine' => '<a target="_blank" href="file://{file}&line={line}">{text}</a>';
        },
    ],
],
```

Firefox should handle such path (as long as you're running app and your IDE on the same machine and your user has rights to read `/var/www` directory).

Answer (score 0):

```php
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'traceLine' => '<a href="http://localhost:63342/api/file?file={file}&line={line}" onclick="var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(\'GET\',this.href);a.send(null);return!1">{text}</a>',
    ];
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/172